# Email as noun and verb

Tags: word-choice, vocabulary, loanwords

Could you guys and gals clarify how you use Email as noun and verb please?

My textbook uses 电子邮件 as a noun and 发电子邮件 as a verb (send an Email). I have also found 伊妹儿 in a dictionary, which looks like transliteration.

So my questions are:

1. Is transliterated version used only as a noun or as a verb as well?
2. Which one of them is used in general?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you should avoid 伊妹儿 (that almost looks like a girls' name or person name). **电子邮件** is the preferred and widely used term.

If you need a verb to express 'to send an e-mail', use 发 with 电子邮件:

E.g. `请给我发个电子邮件`。 Please send me an e-mail.

Comment: I'm sorry, I did use a wrong stroke. It's 发电子邮件 in my textbook. I updated my question accordingly

Comment: @UVV Some more info: for 伊妹儿 you get around 300k results on Google, for 电子邮件 about 50 million. That alone should convince you. Besides, 伊 is a valid surname (Yi), 妹 is 'sister' and 儿 is 'son', it might confuse people who are not familiar with the term. 电子邮件 on the other hand is widely known.

Answer (score 0):

I think some people also just say `发个email。`电子邮件 though is definitely used more than the transliterated version. I'm not sure it's used more than just the English word.

Answer (score 0):

伊妹兒 is just a translation of the word email. The pronunciation (pinyin: `yī​mèir`) is very similar to email. But avoid it when writing stuff. I think it's just for informal conversations.